# Spring Security 6+ throw 403 if authenticated user doesn't have any role

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

How can Spring Security be set up to verify whether a user possesses any role? Specifically, an authenticated endpoint lacking a pre-defined mandatory role should be off-limits unless the user holds at least one role; in such cases, access should be granted

Answer (score -2):

You should create a SecurityFilterChain to achieve something like you describe. For example:

```
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/journey").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

This is what you want? Optimal solution for described by you situation is to setting up proper configuration for specific enpoints and use .hasAnyRole method passing through them all posibilities for the role.

I can imagine some special logic using custom filters, but it can involve too much effort. And it's better to handle authorizations using above (preffered) solution, so as not to introduce confusion into our code.

Of course in my example I specified the code example to handle only what you mentioned in your question.

Is it what you need?

Another solution if you only want to check if user has assigned to them any role you can create separate filter for this.

```
public class RoleCheckFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (hasAnyAssignedRole(authentication)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }


    // User doesn't have any assigned role, you can handle this as needed
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN); // For example, return a 403 Forbidden
}

private boolean hasAnyAssignedRole(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication != null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(authentication.getAuthorities());
}
```

}

Furthermore if you want to check for only roles, not any authority, you can filter authorities by filtering them to these which started from 'ROLE' string.

After creating this filter you should put them in the right place in the filter chain. Like:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(new RoleCheckFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Is this what you suppose to achieve?

Comment: not exactly, I need like: .hasAnyRole("Here can be any role name")

Comment: But you want to apply checking if user has any role to specific endpoints? Or you want to only check first if the user has any role?

Comment: first => check if user has at least one role, second => if an endpoint requires specific one, check if the user has needed role. Basically I want to avoid adding to each secured endpoint (w/o specified role) something like @WithRoles custom secured annotation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).